# Escaping quotation marks from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a json

```
var str  = '{"name": "Sam", "address": [{"street": "Main St"}, {"street": "2nd Street"}]}';
```

Now to remove the double quotes from value of address, I do

```
var street = '[{"street": "Main St"}, {"street": "2nd Street"}]';

street = street.replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');

str = '{"name": "Sam", "address": "'+street+'"}'
```

which gives

```
{"name": "Sam", "address": "[{\"street\": \"Main St\"}, {\"street\": \"2nd Street\"}]"}"
```

But if i do `JSON.stringify(str)`, I end up with

```
"{\"name\": \"Sam\", \"address\": \"[{\\\"street\\\": \\\"Main St\\\"}, {\\\"street\\\": \\\"2nd Street\\\"}]\"}
```

My question is, what is the right way to escape double quotes from a JSON string.

Comment: why do you need to escape those quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not create an object, as opposed to a string?

```
var obj   = {name: "Sam", address: [{street: "Main St"}, {street: "2nd Street"}]};
JSON.stringify(obj);
```